# Проблема определением наличия слова

Tags: javascript

Есть переменная `val` с содержимым `285 кривой` или `ровный %`. Как определить имеется ли слово в переменной `val`?

```
var val = "285 кривой";
if (!val.indexOf("Кривой" || "ровный") + 1) {
    console.log("нет");
} else {
    console.log("есть");
}
```

Comment: getElementById("285 кривой") ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно изменить условие и сделать две разные проверки с помощью [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), а не писать условия в параметры.

```js
var val = "285 кривой";
if (val.indexOf("кривой") >= 0 || val.indexOf("ровный") >= 0) {
  console.log("есть");
} else {
  console.log("нет");
}
```

Comment: Если мне надо чтобы было в ветви `да`, ответ был что переменная `var` не содержит слов `кривой` или `ровный`. Надо изменить `>= 0`?

Comment: `indexOf` возвращает символ, с которого искомая подстрока входит в строку. Пример: "285 кривой", искомая строка "кривой", то indexOf вернет 4. Если результат -1, то значит подстрока не найдена. Если вы хотите сделать отрицательные значения, то есть два варианта или сравнивать результат `indexOf` с `-1`, или поставить перед val.indexOf() восклицательный знак.

Answer (score 1):

Так как у вас - не заработает, потому что оператор отрицания выполнится раньше чем оператор сложения

```js
var indexOf = -1; // Слово не найдено
console.log(!indexOf + 1 ); // Условие выполняется

indexOf = 0; // Слово найдено
console.log(!indexOf + 1 ); // Условие выполняется
```

Пример использования indexOf дали в соседнем ответе, поэтому предложу метод [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```js
var val = "285 кривой";
if (val.includes("кривой") || val.includes("ровный")) {
  console.log("есть");
} else {
  console.log("нет");
}
```